# How to sell Super Bitcoin Fork

Tags: blockchain-fork

I would like to sell all the forks of bitcoin especially Super Bitcoin Fork. I can see that Super Bitcoin is traded on few exchanges, but the deposit of Super Bitcoin is disabled or temporary off on all of these exchanges. Is there any way how to sell it?

Answer (score 1):

List of exchanges that seem to be trading Super Bitcoin are listed here https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/super-bitcoin/trading_exchanges

Gate offers the best liquidity at this time. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've found one exchange so far, which seems to still offer SBTC wallet deposit.
https://gate.io/myaccount/deposit/SBTC

But there are now about 8 active nodes and probably none active miner, so you cannot get confirmation on your transaction, so this currency is dead now.